# adding inline style to last li using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, repeater

I would like to add an inline style to the last LI that is generated with the ASP:repeater control.

I can't add a css class, i need to some how count the last li with the class called:

```
class="tile lower-boxes icon_email"
```

Comment: how the repeater generate html code? li:last will give you the last li, but you have to look in its context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I've understood your question, then the following should work for you:

```
$(".tile.lower-boxes.icon_email:last").css("color", "#C00");
```

Obviously, that selector and the CSS method can be changed to your needs. You can also add a class to the element, which would be preferable:

```
$(".tile.lower-boxes.icon_email:last").addClass("foo");
```

More info on the [:last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector.

Comment: is the css method faster on page load or is injecting the inline style?

Comment: They're about the same in terms of performance, however it is better to add a class to the elements so that you can maintain a separate style sheet and not have to worry about sporadic bits of styling information in your markup. Separation of concerns etc.

Comment: my css path to the last li looks like this: **html body.theme_teal section#page_home.page ul.tiles form#form1 ul li.tile** but doesnt appear to have applied the style, i even have document.ready. Ill accept your answer anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Jquery has a [last function](http://api.jquery.com/last/) that will let you choose it functionally.

```
$('li.tile').last()
```

or you can use the :last selector

```
$('li.tile:last')
```

Edit: Fix Bad link

Comment: I didn't understand the link on last question text.

Answer (score 0):

we can also use jQuery :last Selector..

e.g:

```
$("li:last").css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

*I know the question is quite old but thought it might be helpful for others ..*